# Task scheduling in AppEngine dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a [python] AppEngine app which creates multiple tasks and adds them to a custom task queue. dev_appserver.py seems to ignore the rate/scheduling parameters I specify in queue.yaml and executes all the tasks immediately. This is a problem [as least for dev/testing purposes] as my tasks call a rate-throttled url; immediate execution of all tasks breaches the throttling limits and returns me a bunch of errors.

Does anyone know if task scheduling if dev_appserver.py is disabled ? I can't find anything that suggests this in the AppEngine docs. Can anyone suggest a workaround ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

When your app is running in the development server, **tasks are automatically executed at the appropriate time just as in production**.
You can examine and manipulate tasks from the developer console:
http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/taskqueue

Documentation [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html#Task_Queues_and_the_Development_Server)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. "automatically executed at the appropriate time" - that's not my experience. Eg if I specify queue.yaml rate as '6/m' and bucket_size as 1 then I'd expect to get one task executed every 10 secs; instead they all get executed immediately. So I'm asking if anyone else has had a similar experience; if I've configured queue.yaml incorrectly or if perhaps there is a problem with dev_appserver task scheduling.

Comment: I'm reading the queue.yaml docs now. I can see that 6/m means "tasks will be processed at a rate of 6 times per minute"; but there's no guarantee it's every 10 secs. But how does adding a rate of 10/s help ? Doesn't this mean you get 10 tasks per second [rather than one every 10 secs] ? Or do you mean there's a separate 'rate_limit' field ? [can't see one]. Thanks

Comment: Ok - thanks - then back to the original question. Firstly, I started with a rate of 6/m and 24 tasks, yet all 24 tasks were executed inside of a minute. So this suggests to me that task scheduling is not working on dev_appserver.py. Secondly, can anyone suggest how to configure queue.yaml so a task is processed every ten seconds ? [or at least the rate is no quicker than ten seconds]

Comment: @Just could you share your code [queue.yaml+task submission]?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Python_Push_queues_and_the_development_server) lies: the development server doesn't appear to support rate limiting. (This [is documented](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Java_Push_queues_and_the_development_server) for the Java dev server, but not for Python). You can demonstrate this by pausing a queue by giving it a 0/s rate, but you'll find it executes tasks anyway. When such an app is uploaded to production, it behaves as expected.

I opened a [defect](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9760&thanks=9760&ts=1375134242).

Comment: Can you share the link to the reported issue, please. i believe this hasn't been resolved.

Comment: It's linked from the word "defect".

Answer (score 0):

Rate parameter is not used for setting absolute upper bounds of TaskQueue processing. In fact, if you use for example:

`rate: 10/s

bucket_size: 20`

the processing can burst up to 20/s. Something more useful would be:

`max_concurrent_requests: 1`

which sets the maximum number of execution to 1 at a time.

However, this will not stop tasks from executing. If you are adding multiple Tasks a time but know that they need to be executed at a later time, you should probably use **countdown**.

[_countdown using deferred library](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html)
[countdown using Task class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html)